# Why isn't my UITableView appearing in the correct scroll position?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a split view-based app that presents a master-detail interface, and uses a popover to present the master list when in portrait mode. The popover presents a sectioned table view that ultimately gets populated by a subclass of `NSFetchedResultsController`. I can tap the tool bar button to present the master list, scroll to whatever row, and tap the row to dismiss the popover.

My problem is that if the table is scrolled past the top of the second section, when I dismiss the popover and then later tap the toolbar button to re-present it, the table's scroll position is always set such that the first row of the second section is at the top of the list. If I haven't scrolled past the top of the second section, it correctly remembers its scroll position when the table is presented again.

Similarly, in landscape mode, if I scroll the table past the top of the third section and then rotate to portrait, when I come back to landscape the scroll position is always set such that the first row of the third section is at the top of the list.

I tried calling `-scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:animated` in both the master view controller's `-viewWillAppear`, as well as in the split view delegate's `splitViewController:popoverController:willPresentViewController:`, to no effect. Anybody have a clue what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try storing `tableView.contentOffset`?

```
CGPoint offset = tableView.contentOffset;

...
...
...

[tableView setContentOffset: offset];
```

Comment: How is it that the most frustrating problems so often have such simple solutions? Many thanks for clueing me in to the contentOffset property.